# Posting data from Servlet to Rest webservice

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I want to submit form data to servlet which is `Jersey rest client`
and inside this servlet I have to call a `Restful Webservice`.

I have to pass all form data to that rest Webservice and after that we will get a response object from rest to servlet.

I have to pass this response object directly to `JSP` page here request and response will be in `JSON` format.

Comment: Slightly improved the format. However, a targeted question should be included by OP.

Answer (score 0):

you can use servlet to send data to web service by  `sendRedirect("<url>")`

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to call REST Class from a Servlet?

If so, the following is the way. But your REST call will be treated as a plain class.  To call any method of the Rest class you have to create its object and access its methods.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String requestURI           = req.getRequestURI();

    RestClass restClassObj  = new RestClass();

    String parameter1 = "";
    String parameter2 = "";
    String parameter3 = "";

    String restResponse = "";       
    if(StringUtils.endsWith(requestURI, "services") || StringUtils.endsWith(requestURI, "services/")){
        parameter1 = req.getParameter("parameter1");
        parameter2 = req.getParameter("parameter2");
        parameter3 = req.getParameter("parameter3");

        restResponse = restClassObj.getRestClassMethodResponse(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3);
    }
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.getWriter().write(restResponse);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(req,resp);
}
```

Now the RestClass is,

```
public class RestClass {
    public RestClass() {

    }

    public String getRestClassMethodResponse(@FormParam("parameter1") String parameter1, @FormParam("parameter2") String parameter2, @FormParam("parameter3") String parameter3){

        //Now write your own logic and return the data to the Servlet class in //JSON format

        return jsonResponse;
    }
}
```